# Angular 4 SEO Friendly solution in prod

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying to create a website in Angular 4. It is a base of my personal study.

[My website](http://www.afetter.com) is up and running but I'm trying to improve it. I checked and apparently my website is not SEO Friendly. I make some changes and I discovered this sample https://oliverveits.wordpress.com/2017/07/05/server-side-rendering-in-angular-4-with-universal/ That show an Angular 4 app with Page Source code.

I make the changes, I started to use Webpack and other features sugared by in the link. When I run the command "npm run start" and I access http://localhost:8000 I can see the Page Source. But when I copy the dist to my server on Godaddy domain I can't.

I'm not sure about what I have to do. If I need put my website in a node.js server or if I'm not compiling it correctly to have what I'm expecting.

I'm open to different approachs.

Comment: Angular Universal https://universal.angular.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the what causes this issue.

I think many of new Angular devs possible have the same problem.

When you run "**npm start**" or "**ng s**" what are you doing is put the node to listen a specific port. In other words, you are running a node server.

In another approach, copy the files to an IIS server or Apache Server. This doesn't make the Node Server run. In this scenario, the pages are download to the client browser and run as HTML/javascript page. And because of this when I try to see the Page source I saw the Angular files.

Took me a while to understand it. My background is .Net development.

Now a day my website is running in one of the many node.js servers. [evennode.com](http://evennode.com), on this server instead of to have an IIS or Apache, they set up a Node Server to listing a specific port and then you are able to run all your development on the server side.

I found easier use a node js server like evennode them set tup node js run on my Goddady account.